# How can I take ownership of multiple files in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, file-permissions, file-ownership

Setting it file by file works, but is slow.

Selecting all of them at once doesn't have this configuration.

And the files can't inherit the security properties of the folder because they don't have my ownership.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the command line:

```
takeown /f folder1\folder2\*
```

Comment: I also had to set permissions to all the files of a folder like this: CACLS * /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION}

Answer (score 0):

1. Run command as admin
2. takeown /f *.* /r /a /d y